# React navigation: Infinite reloading of the main screen when using nested navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react native and react navigation. I am trying to create a nested navigator, i.e., I am trying to place a tab navigator within a stack navigator. When I run the app on iOS simulator, however, the main screen reloads infinitely. What might be wrong with the below code? New to react native...bear with me if this is a simple one!

Below is the part of the code where I am doing the nesting:

```
 import React from 'react';
 import Home from './routes/Home'
 import Alert from './routes/Alert'
 import Profile from './routes/Profile'
 import Subs from './routes/Subs'
 import Write from './routes/Write'
 import OtherProfile from './routes/OtherProfile'
 import Post from './routes/Post'
 import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
 import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
 import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
 import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

 export default function App() {
   const MainStack = createStackNavigator();
   const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

   function HomeTab() {
     return (
       <Tab.Navigator>      
         <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
         <Tab.Screen name="Subs" component={Subs}/>
         <Tab.Screen name="Write" component={Write} options={{ tabBarVisible: false }}/>
         <Tab.Screen name="Alert" component={Alert}/>
         <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile}/>
       </Tab.Navigator>
     )
   }

   function MainStackScreen() {
     return (
       <MainStack.Navigator>
         <MainStack.Screen name="HomeTab" component={HomeTab} options = {{ headerShown: false }} />
         <MainStack.Screen name="Post" component={Post} />
         <MainStack.Screen name="OtherProfile" component={OtherProfile} />
       </MainStack.Navigator>
     )
   }

   return (
   <NavigationContainer>
     <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
         <MainStackScreen/>
     </SafeAreaView>
   </NavigationContainer>
   )
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer right after posting this.
I declared the navigators and the navigation components outside of the App component and it works.